# Netgear DHCP server doesn't provide the inputted dns servers to the connecting computer

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, wireless-router, dhcp

I have NETGEAR JWNR2010v3 Router and I have configured it to static IP provided by the ISP. I have configured the preferred and alternate DNS servers provided by the ISP into the router.

When I connect my computer to the router, the IP Address it gets for "Preferred DNS server" and "Alternate DNS server" is the router's own IP Address i.e. 192.168.1.1 rather the ones that I have configured into the router.

This causes problems, that when I connect the internet works, but after a few hours of idle, when I try to browse, I have to restart the router or apply the settings again and reconnect.

I can enter those IP Address values for preferred and alternate dns servers manually on the computer, but that is not the way, every computer I connect, I will have to do that.

Is there any solution for this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit the DHCP server settings in the Netgear and add the DNS server you want the clients to receive there.

Comment: There are no DHCP server settings in the router, the only thing that is there is in the picture I have attached.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 would allow the router to handle the DNS not the client.  Which by the sounds of it is exactly what you want.  If thats not what you want configured the DNS on the client also.

Comment: If I try checking the "Domain Name Server (DNS) Address" radio box, it is ignored completely - I can't even enter anything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the router is doing and the pages you're seeing.

**"LAN SETUP"**

This page simply configures your LAN.

IP Address: This is the IP of your router as seen by your LAN - "the gateway".
Subnet: This is the subnet that your LAN devices will be put on

DHCP: Start-End range - this is the "pool" of addresses your DHCP server will give out to connecting LAN devices. You can give your LAN devices "static" addresses if you prefer, but they must be outside of the start and end numbers given here, and within the number of IPs available inside the subnet you have chosen.

**"BASIC SETTINGS" (Your Internet settings page)**

The IP and DNS settings configured here are what your router uses to connect to the Internet - the settings have nothing to do with your LAN.

When a computer on your LAN makes a request to "the Internet" is forwards the request to the router -> the router checks to see if the request can be completed on the LAN -> if the request can't be completed on the LAN it sends the request to its gateway (your ISP and, thus, the Internet) and uses the DNS IPs given on the page.

**ANSWER**

What you're trying to do (send all your LAN devices the DNS IPs from your router) cannot be done using the router you have. To "push" DNS addresses to your LAN requires more advanced router equipment.

It seems you have a problem with either your ISP modem or the router itself...

Comment: But the other router that I have - DLINK DWR 113, pushes the DNS Server  Addresses to the connecting machines when DHCP is turned on in it.

Comment: I don't have any problem in not getting DNS addresses from router, but then if not done, then after few hours of being idle, the internet shows connected on computer but can't be browsed through. But as soon as I provide those DNS addresses in the preferred and alternate dns server boxes, it starts working.

Comment: And this should be correct, because it is also written in the Netgear documentation. I have update the question to attach the screenshot of documentation.

Comment: The documentation you have submitted isn't for the router you're using... the address you have posted is for the DG834N RangeMax. Essentially the screen settings are the same, but the device functionality may differ.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea then, why it stops working if kept idle for few hours, if I don't manually enter DNS addresses?

Comment: Power settings of your computer network adapter?